# How to get splicing method working with both strings and lists

Tags: string, list, function, python-3.x, splice

I am fairly new to all of this programming and Python. So I just had a question regarding the Splicing method.

here is the code:

```
function(seq, n)
return seq[:n]
```

It is hard to explain what I want done with it but this is what the output should look like. I am sure u intellegent people will understand.

```
function([5, 3, 7, 2, 8], 3)
```

output:

```
[8, 2, 5, 3, 7]
```

or

```
function("ACEJY3529",4)
```

output:

```
'3529YACEJ'
```

Its sort of like swapping positions...

So the problem is that, this code works fine with integers... but when I use strings, it crashes...

Comment: In the first test case, what happened to 2? Shouldn't that be `[2, 8, 5, 3, 7]`?

Comment: OHH Ur right ! ... I didnt notice that... the 2 should have been there the outut should have looked like:

[8,2,5,3,7]

Comment: Someone was telling me to use the Loop function... in order to complete this task...

Comment: @user2891763 that single item list of `[parameter2]` looks odd - I'm guessing you mean `parameter1[parameter2]` so you get a single item (be it a `str` or `int`) from `parameter1`

Comment: @Jon Clements: When I do that, it gives me an error:

builtins.TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: @user2891763 make it a single item list `[parameter1[parameter2]]` for instance...

Comment: Oh Thanks it worked and fixed the error I was getting where the 2 was being replaced by the 3... Now the output is correct.

Comment: But when I run it with ("ACEJY3529",4)  .. it is giving error: builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: @user2891763 any particular reason you've removed the code from your question?

Comment: I just realized.. leaving the code there could lead to plagiarism.. Because that is the exact code I am using...

Comment: @user2891763 That's not how SO works - it's in your benefit you leave the code - in fact - without it - your question makes no sense and would have shown no effort on your part to solve it and would have been closed (very quickly). (And, it'd take more effort to find that single line of code to solve a task that very few people could want - than to just write the bloomin' thing :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most generic way is to always deal with slices and not individual items, eg:

```
def function(seq, n):
    return seq[n+1:] + seq[n:n+1] + seq[:n]
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

We always make that a length 1 iterable rather than a non iterable single item.

Comment: THANKS !!!! U HELPED ME solve this problem... But one last thing if u dont mind... could u please expand upon why you did :  seq[n:n+1]  ... why make that "a length 1 iterable rather than a non iterable single item"

Comment: @user2891763 well have a little play with it... see what differences you notice between `seq[n]` and `seq[n:n+1]` :0...